# Magento 1.9.3.7 upgrade issue

Tags: upgrade, magento1.9.3, magento-upgrade

Magento 1.9.3.7 released which fixes some critical vulnerabilities and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1936

Here, we are talking about version upgrade issues.

Please share the bugs you are facing while upgrading to Magento 1.9.3.7.

Comment: I have upgraded website from 1.9.3.0 to 1.9.3.7 but magereport still showing patch 8788, 9767 and 10415 showing unpatched.

Comment: Hi @MattAntley, Can you please tell me how its a duplicate of link you have given? Patch installation and Magento upgrade both are diffrent.